# Ping Pong players

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

A and B play ping pong game  multiple times. The person serving first has a probability p of winning that game. A serves the first game and thereafter the loser serves first.

If p(n) = pbt that A wins nth game,then: p(n) = p*p(n-1) + (1-p)*(1-p(n-1))

Is that just because:

If A wins the n-1th game, pbt he wins nth game = p.

If A loses the n-1th game, pbt he wins nth game = 1-p

I am probably missing something.

Comment: Yes, what you wrote is a *recurrence* for $p(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(n)$ be the probability A wins the $n$-th game. We assume that what you have written is correct, that the **loser** of the previous game serves first, and that the person who serves first in a game has probability $p$ of winning the game.

For any $n\ge 2$, the event "A wins the $n$-th game" can happen in two disjoint ways: (i) A won the previous game, and then wins or (ii) A lost the previous game, and then wins.

The probability of event (i) is $p(n-1)(1-p)$. For the post says that the *loser* of the previous game serves first. *Given* that A won the previous game, she does not serve first in the next, and therefore her conditional probability of winning the next is $1-p$.  So the probability she wins the $(n-1)$-th game *and* wins the $n$-th is $p(n-1)(1-p)$.

The probability of event (ii) is $(1-p(n-1))p$. Thus
$$p(n)= (1-p)p(n-1)+p(1-p(n-1)).$$

**Remarks:** The formula we obtained is a *recurrence* formula for $p(n)$. Note it is not quite the same as yours, which perhaps explains why justifying yours caused puzzlement.

One can use the recurrence formula to obtain an explicit formula for $p(n)$ as a function of $n$.

I should have changed have changed $p(k)$ to something like $a_k$ to make expressions easier to read.